# What shape is the Sage logo

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

[image]

Just curious what is this shape used by Sage as its logo?

Comment: Not some regular"gon" as far as I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An accepted answer in the [Q&A section](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/7667/geometric-name-of-sage-logo-existence-of-dual/) (similar to here!) of Sage official website claims that this is just a graph (piece of art) without geometric meaning.

I personally don't see how this claim is justified in that post over there, but the info of the artist is corroborated by [their own wiki](https://wiki.sagemath.org/logos).

Maybe one can try to contact this artist and ask him/her/them directly.